# How can i fetch graphql api endpoint data in react with class components?

Tags: reactjs

so I have a GRAPHQL server running locally and I need to fetch data in my react app and I have to build that app with class components. how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a library like [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request#quickstart). You will call the request in one of the lifecycle methods if you are using class components and not functional components. You can set the result into state and use it from there.

```
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request'

const query = gql`
  {
    Movie(title: "Inception") {
      releaseDate
      actors {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`

request('https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/movies', query).then((data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i will definitely try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_DATA = gql`
// your data goes here
`
export class App extends Component{
render(){

    return(
     <Query query={GET_DATA}>
        {({ error, loading, data }) => {
        if (error) return 'something went wrong';
        if (loading) return 'loading...';
        if (data) console.log(data)
    </Query
    
    )

    }

}
```